# Noise Tags - Do we need them all?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

At present we have four tags related to noise in images as follows: (numbers of questions in brackets)

- **[noise](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise)** (34)
- **[noise-reduction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise-reduction)** (23)
- **[noise-removal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise-removal)** (7)
- **[iso-noise](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iso-noise)** (15)

As I see it:

`noise` is the general tag and suitable for questions related to what noise is, or for questions such as [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/what-is-iso-on-a-digital-camera) where noise is not the main focus of the question, but is clearly a part of it.

`noise-reduction` is for questions such as [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8276/how-do-i-reduce-noise-given-that-i-have-complete-control-over-everything-else), where the question is about minimising the amount of noise in an image in the first place, and `noise-removal` is to do with post-processing photos to remove noise that is in an image.

I see little need for `iso-noise`, as at the moment it seems to mostly be used to tag questions that are related to noise (but necessarily due solely to ISO, such as [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10128/are-hot-pixels-just-one-pixel)) or already contain both the `iso` and `noise` tags, such as [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/what-is-iso-on-a-digital-camera).

What does everyone else think? Should I start re-tagging to tidy these tags up as per the above?

Answer (score 3):

I think we can merge the tag `[iso-noise]` into `[noise]`, as the two are ideal synonyms. I think the use of `[noise-reduction]` and `[noise-removal]` is pretty obvious. If those tags do not contain tag wikis, we should probably create some. If noise is related to iso, tagging with `[noise]` and `[iso]` should be enough to indicate that fact.

Comment: I created very basic tag wikis for `[noise-reduction]` and `[noise-removal]` and removed one or other tag from questions that had both but only were about one.